# Java's mkdir failure

Tags: java, tomcat, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory by java's mkdir method.

The problem that it fails and I think because of access restriction.
Tomcat is running under tomcat7 user, the folder's owner is tomcat7 user too. Every subfolder has the same owner. But still this method fails (the path is valid).

Does anybody familiar with such problem?
Thank you

Comment: Note that `mkdir()` will return `false` if the directory already exists. Do all subfolders exist? If not, use `mkdirs()`.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Is an SecurityException thrown?

Comment: There are no exceptions because mkdir doesn't throw any of them...

Comment: Strange, I added the dir.canWrite check and it returned false everytime but actually I can write to that directory

Comment: what is the error message your getting?
Please check my code to create folder(Given below)

Comment: @FathahRehmanP As I said the problem was in canWrite() method, don't know why but it return false on the directory that I actually can write

Comment: which method you used to create directory mkdir() or mkdirs()?

Comment: Are you *sure* that the user permissions are correct? If you are running as a Windows Service, you usually aren't running as yourself but some non-privileged user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class TestClass6 {
        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String path = "c:/folder1/folder2";    // path of the folder you want to create
        File folder=new File(path);
        boolean exist=folder.exists();
        if(!exist){
            folder.mkdirs();
        }else{
            System.out.println("folder already exist");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code can still fail if a file exists with the name `folder2`. Instead of just `exists`, you should also call `isDirectory`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the directory exists before hand. `mkdir` returns false if the directory already exists.
So, a pseudocode is:

```
if exists(dir):
   move on and do other things
else:
   File f = new File(dir);
   f.mkdir();
```

Also, make sure you have `w` (write) permissions in the directory you're using as your base directory.